# Passing values from layout to nested child routes in svelte sapper?

Tags: svelte, sapper, svelte-3

[Edit] I've updated the example to include both using preload (`userb`) and {#await} (`usera`). Both scenarios usera and userb are undefined in `/users/[username]/about.svelte`

how would you get something like this to work:

/users/[username]/_layout.svelte

```
{#await promise}
  Loading...
  <slot {usera} {userb}/>
{:then usera}
  { JSON.stringify({usera, userb}) }
  <slot {usera} {userb}/>
{/await}

<script context="module">
    export async function preload(page, session) {
        let userb = await fetchUser(page.params.username)
        return { userb };
    }
</script>

<script>
import { stores } from '@sapper/app'
const { page } = stores();

export let userb;
let usera

async function fetchUser (username) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve({ username });
  }, 333))
}

let promise = fetchUser($page.params.username)
</script>
```

/users/[username]/about.svelte

```
{#if usera}
  <span>{usera.username}</span>
{:else}
 NULL USER_A
{/if}

{#if userb}
  <span>{userb.username}</span>
{:else}
 NULL USER_B
{/if}

<script>
export let usera
export let userb

$: console.log({ usera })
$: console.log({ userb })
</script>
```

It seems like /user/:username/about isn't receiving the prop user from _layout. This works in nuxt (basically sapper for vuejs instead of svelte).

Comment: are you using a `preload` function in your layout?

Comment: No. Is that something I should try?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your proload function. Check out the docs around preloading at https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Preloading

You should have something like this in your code. The preloading is necessary in order to load the data before the page renders. And it only works if you include it in the script with module context (`<script context="module">`)

```html
{#await userPromise}
  <p>...waiting</p>
{:then user}
  <slot {user}></slot>
{:catch error}
  <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}

<script context="module">
  export async function preload({ params }) {
    console.log('layout')
    const { username } = params;
    return { username };
  }
</script>

<script>
  function delay(t, v) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, v), t);
    });
  }
  export let username;
  export let userPromise = fetchUser($page.params.username)
</script>
```

Comment: I added a preload function but it's still not working either way.